# Core plot, how to change color of negative axis tick labels

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am making a graph in objective-c by using the core-plot library, I want to change the color of negative axis labels? How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

There are least three different ways to do this, depending on how much flexibility you need.

1. Use two y-axis. Set them up identically, except set the visible range on one to cover the positive values and the other the negative values. Set the `labelTextStyle` and/or `labelFormatter` for each one as desired.
2. Use an axis delegate and implement the `-axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:` delegate method. Return NO and make custom labels at each of the provided locations. This works with any labeling policy.

   ```
   -(BOOL)axis:(CPTAxis *)axis shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations:(NSSet *)locations
   {
       static CPTTextStyle *positiveStyle = nil;
       static CPTTextStyle *negativeStyle = nil;

       NSNumberFormatter *formatter = axis.labelFormatter;
       CGFloat labelOffset          = axis.labelOffset;
       NSDecimalNumber *zero        = [NSDecimalNumber zero];

       NSMutableSet *newLabels = [NSMutableSet set];

       for ( NSDecimalNumber *tickLocation in locations ) {
           CPTTextStyle *theLabelTextStyle;

           if ( [tickLocation isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:zero] ) {
               if ( !positiveStyle ) {
                   CPTMutableTextStyle *newStyle = [axis.labelTextStyle mutableCopy];
                   newStyle.color = [CPTColor greenColor];
                   positiveStyle  = newStyle;
               }
               theLabelTextStyle = positiveStyle;
           }
           else {
               if ( !negativeStyle ) {
                   CPTMutableTextStyle *newStyle = [axis.labelTextStyle mutableCopy];
                   newStyle.color = [CPTColor redColor];
                   negativeStyle  = newStyle;
               }
               theLabelTextStyle = negativeStyle;
           }

           NSString *labelString       = [formatter stringForObjectValue:tickLocation];
           CPTTextLayer *newLabelLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelString style:theLabelTextStyle];

           CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithContentLayer:newLabelLayer];
           newLabel.tickLocation = tickLocation.decimalValue;
           newLabel.offset       = labelOffset;

           [newLabels addObject:newLabel];

           [newLabel release];
           [newLabelLayer release];
       }

       axis.axisLabels = newLabels;

       return NO;
   }
   ```
3. Use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy. This is the most flexible, but also the most work since you have to compute the tick locations in addition to making the custom labels.

Comment: Thanks for these solutions, In 1st way I have to define the +ve/-ve range by myself but I am using automatic range defined by core plot for my given data. For 2nd way can you list the delegate name of axis and definition of -axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations: this and in this delegate method how I will separate +ve axis and -ve?

Comment: Look at the location when making the label. Use that to decide what text style to use.

Comment: Eric, I used CPTAxisDelegate and implemented -axis:shouldUpdateAxisLabelsAtLocations: this into my .m file but this method is not triggering there. Can you list any example of it?

Comment: Did you set `axis.delegate` to the delegate object?

Comment: yup axis.delegate = self my interface is having this CPTAxisDelegate delegate.

Comment: I've added the code from option #2 to the iPhone version of CPTTestApp. See the changes here: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=b68687239a518d9d236aaa6fd61cedeae1deef77